# Convert a number from string to integer without using inbuilt function

Tags: c++

I am trying this technique but error is coming. Please help me to convert a number from string to integer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *buffer[80];
    int a;

    cout<<"enter the number";
    cin.get(buffer,79);

    char *ptr[80] = &buffer;
    while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        a=(a*10)+(*ptr-48);
    }
    cout<<"the value"<<a;

    delete ptr[];

    return 0;
}
```

Errors are:

1. error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char *(*)[80]' to 'char *[80]'
2. error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'int'

Comment: What is the error? Which line is generating it? What have you already tried in order to fix it?

Comment: @Raja - If this is school-related and/or homework, the general suggestion is to label it as homework (homework c++).

Comment: You aren't converting the integer _characters_ inputted by the user to their integer value.

Comment: @jared Farrish it is not an homework.i was trying this program to conver a number in a string to number.and i am using this technique.but unable get to write code.so i posted my question here

Comment: @ GWW i got the idea to use this                                       while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        a=(a*10)+(*ptr-48);
    }                                                                so using in my program

Comment: @Raja - That's fine. It has the appearance of being homework. Homework is ok and people will help anyway, so if it is homework, labeling it as such prevents a lot of condescending comments. If it's not, then don't worry about it. :)

Comment: Won't the `while` loop become an infinite loop unless you advance the pointer or change the value being pointed to? I don't see where that happens in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tal has mentioned, you are creating buffers of `char*` but you treat them like buffers of `char`. However, the recommended C++ way is not to use raw buffers at all:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string buffer;
    int a = 0;

    cout<<"enter the number";
    cin >> buffer;

    for(string::iterator it = buffer.begin(); it != buffer.end(); ++it)
    {
        a=(a*10) + (*it-48);
    }
    cout<<"the value"<<a;

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this can be shortened to:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;

    cout<<"enter the number";
    cin >> a;
    cout<<"the value"<<a;
}
```

But that already uses library functions.

**EDIT:** Also fixed `int a`not being initialized. That caused your program return garbage.

Comment: @dark_charlie: then one could use a stringstream, too :) ... seems like homework to me.

Comment: @ dark_charlie the answer is accepted.but i want to ask one point that i dont know to use what u have used in your i.e           for(string::iterator it = buffer.begin(); it != buffer.end(); ++it)   will you tell with using pointer for my convience

Comment: @Raja: Iterators are generalized pointers - they behave like pointers (mostly) but are safer to use. As a simplification, you can think of the loop as if the variable `it` were a pointer (char *) and buffer.end() were '\0'.

Comment: Dont't use Magic numbers (48). Use the appropriate platform specific constant. =>  '0'  This will always work.

Comment: Note: The use second version also takes into consideration local (ie numbers can have a thousand separator if you set the local appropriately: ie 1,000,000 will be correct read as a million if you set the local to use ',' as the thousand separator.

Comment: @ dark_charlie thanks.i will make the habbit to do program in your ways.can you tell from where i can learn to use these and standard template library.please Dont refer any book name.please provide some useful website link.

Comment: @Raja: You can use the cprogramming.com tutorials to learn more about those concepts. Especially the part about Standard Template Library (STL): http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html#stltutorial. This (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html) is part of the tutorial that explains iterators.

Answer (score 5):

When you define variables as "char *buffer[80]", you are actually making an array of 80 char pointers instead of an array of size 80. Also, you shouldn't delete anything that was not allocated using new (or delete[] anything that wasn't allocated with new[], in this case).

EDIT: Another thing, you're not actually advancing ptr, so you'll always be looking at the first character.

Comment: ok. i got your point .but the program is'nt working according to me.I want to convert a no. from string to integer.that is using while(*ptr!='\0') { a=(a*10)+(*ptr-48); }

Answer (score 0):

Below will help. I am using this way in my projects.

```
bool stringToInt(std::string numericString, int *pIntValue)
{
    int dVal = 0;
    if (numericString.empty())
        return false;

    for (auto ch : numericString)
    {
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            dVal = (dVal * 10) + (ch - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    *pIntValue = dVal;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    std::string numStr;
    std::cin >> numStr;
    if (!stringToInt(numStr, &num))
        std::cout << "convertionFailed\n";
    return 0;
}
```